Added group to user's secondary groups but still unable to edit (resize) file with permissions 664
The output of groups user1:
group1 group2 group3

The output of ls -l dir/:
total 20
-rw-rw-r--    1 group2  group2        277 Aug 26 01:52 file
...

The output of ls -l outside of dir:
drwxrwxr-x    4 group2  group2       1024 Aug 26 01:57 dir/

The output of cat /etc/group:
...
group3:x:5:user1
...
group2:x:397:user1
...
group1:x:400:user1
user1:x:401:
...

Program (cpp) to resize file (original link):
// was mostly copied from original link above
// program tldr: it just prints the user uid and groups and tries to resize `dir/file` to size 0
std::cout << "user uid " << getuid() << "\n";

struct passwd* pw = getpwuid(getuid());
if(pw == NULL){
    perror("getpwuid error: ");
}

int ngroups = 0;

//this call is just to get the correct ngroups
getgrouplist(pw->pw_name, pw->pw_gid, NULL, &ngroups);
__gid_t groups[ngroups];

//here we actually get the groups
getgrouplist(pw->pw_name, pw->pw_gid, groups, &ngroups);

//example to print the groups name
std::string groups_str = "";
for (int i = 0; i < ngroups; i++){
    struct group* gr = getgrgid(groups[i]);
    if(gr == NULL){
        perror("getgrgid error: ");
    }
    groups_str.append(gr->gr_name);
    groups_str.append(" ");
}

std::cout << "user groups " << groups_str << "\n";


auto const path = std::filesystem::path("dir") / "file";
try {
    std::filesystem::resize_file(path, 0);
} catch (std::filesystem::filesystem_error const& e) {
    std::cout << "exception " << e.what() << "\n";
    return;
}

Output from program:
user uid 401
user groups group1 group2 group3
exception filesystem error: cannot resize file: Permission denied [dir/file]

If I chown the file dir/file to uid:gid group3:group3 (or even group1:group3) it works but not for either group1 or group2.
Notes:

Even though I'm using a program to resize the file I don't think the issue is with the program size it works for group3 (the program is only written because it runs in a modified kernel where you can't use any of the commands to change/switch users)
I added group2 to user1 secondary groups through /etc/group since I can't add users/groups with useradd or usermod (those commands are also disabled in the modified kernel)
The directory dir/ is mounted to tmp/dir2 but the permissions and ownerships look correct in the mounted location too:

Output of ls -l tmp/
drwxrwxr-x    4 group2  group2       1024 Aug 26 01:57 dir2/

Output of ls -l tmp/dir2
-rw-rw-r--    1 group2  group2        277 Aug 26 01:52 file


Was it syscalls removed or was it commands removed for user switching? If it really is a modified kernel with some of the user-switching syscalls removed, then I don't think we can really help you with that, as it's impossible for us to know what else has been removed or changed. For all I know, it might have been patched to ignore setgrouplist() as well, or something like that.

Ah I just figured out what happened and in essence it was an issue with some other custom program running on the kernel... so TLDR: grawity_u1686 was correct

It was an issue found in another custom program running on the kernel that used setgroups() to hardcode the secondary groups regardless of what was in /etc/group.
Pretty embarrassing and I'm kicking myself for not figuring that out earlier.
